# Open SecondViewController on startup insted FirstViewController

Tags: ios, redirect, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have TabBarController with two navigations controllers as on an attached image.
If my app will be run first time should be opened Second View Controller.

For navigation controllers I use below code:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    cysViewController *cvc =[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cysViewController"];
    questionViewController *qvc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"questionViewController"];
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    nav.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cvc,qvc, nil];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController popToViewController:qvc animated:NO];
```

but for tabBarController I have no idea how to do that.

[image: my controllers]

Comment: try setSelectedViewController:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the selected index by changing the value of `selectedIndex`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```